# Change alert info text color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using bootstrap 3 and I want to change the text color of the alert info and alert
danger,I want that the texts become darker,how should I do that ?

I search in bootstrap and I've found the following but didnt find the text color...

```
    .alert-info {
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9edf7 0%, #b9def0 100%);
      background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9edf7 0%, #b9def0 100%);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffd9edf7', endColorstr='#ffb9def0', GradientType=0);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      border-color: #9acfea;

}
```

Comment: text colour is set with "color". So color:red;

Comment: this is more of a CSS question (on changing text color) rather than bootstrap specific

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [Alerts section](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) on Bootstrap's own website and through the unminfied CSS on [their Github repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) I can't find any of the CSS you've specified. Instead I can only find the following:

```css
.alert-info {
    color: #31708F;
    background-color: #D9EDF7;
    border-color: #BCE8F1;
}
```

If you want to make the `color` darker, you can use a tool like http://paletton.com to generate some complimentary darker colours:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot voted up,which property is related to text ?and how should I override it in my site file?

Comment: Thanks ,I've two last question :) 1.how should I override this in my site css? 2.there is a way using the paletton to take the color #31708F and simpley make it darker (little bit)?

Comment: Simply use `.alert-info { color: your_color; }` I've already given you the result from plugging `#31708F` in to Paletton: `#1A5E7F` is slightly darker and `#0D4864` is much darker.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the [customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)!

If you want more flexibility, download the [source code](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download), modify the `variables.less` and use `LESS` to compile it to CSS.

Intresting for you is the `@alert-info-bg` variable. Check out `mixins/alerts.ess` and `alerts.less` to see how the other colors are generated.